# Split multiple times?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

So I'm currently transferring a txt file into a csv. It's mostly cleaned up, but even after splitting there are still empty columns between some of my data.

Below is my messy CSV file
[image: Messy_CSV_FILE]
And here is my current code:

```
Sat_File = '/Users'
output = '/Users2'
import csv
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd
with open(Sat_File,'r') as sat:
    with open(output,'w') as outfile:
        if "2004" in line:
            line=line.split('  ')
            writer=csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Basically, I'm just trying to eliminate those gaps between columns in the CSV picture I've provided. Thank you!

Comment: You imported pandas. Why do you use the CSV reader at all when `pandas.read_csv() `is way better than it?

Comment: Try simply line.split() instead of line.split('  ').

Comment: Honestly, just lack of know-how at this point. Very new to python and even more new to the Pandas package. I'll try pandas.read_csv() though! If that works I'll get back with ya!

Comment: @Kantal well how do ya do, that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python Pandas library to clear out the empty columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_csv_file').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df.to_csv('path_to_clean_csv_file')
```

Basically we:

1. Import the pandas library.
2. Read the csv file into a variable called df (stands for data frame).
   Than we use the dropna function that allows to discard empty columns/rows.    axis=1 means drop columns (0 means rows) and how='all' means drop columns all of the values in them are empty.
3. We save the clean data frame df to a new, clean csv file.

$$$ Pr0f!t $$$